# Flatten a key value pair in Rxjs 5

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have the following JSON string being returned from a http request.

```
{
  "RootID": "85cac01a90fe4203aae78523dc6cda41",
  "SubNode": {
    "Key1": [{
        "InternalData1": "1",
        "InternalData2": "2"
      },
      {
        "InternalData1": "3",
        "InternalData2": "4"
      }
    ],
    "Key2": [{
        "InternalData1": "5",
        "InternalData2": "6"
      },
      {
        "InternalData1": "7",
        "InternalData2": "8"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am using Rxjs 5 and I want to flatten the dataset and return values as follows

```
{
  "InternalData1": "1",
  "InternalData2": "2"
}, {
  "InternalData1": "3",
  "InternalData2": "4"
}, {
  "InternalData1": "5",
  "InternalData2": "6"
}, {
  "InternalData1": "7",
  "InternalData2": "8"
}
```

What operator could help me do it?

Comment: `InternalData3` and `InternalData4` don't appear in the input, so this makes no sense. Anyway, you don't need to use RxJS to do what you want. Just use the `Object.keys` and `reduce`.

Comment: Thanks. I have now corrected the question.

Comment: `var flattened = Object.keys(value.SubNode).reduce((acc, key) => [...acc, ...value.SubNode[key]], [])`

Comment: That works. Thanks. Is there a way that I could perform this transformation and forward the transformed data to be used by subscription? I tried `http.get('url').do(x=>return flattenUsingReduce(x))` which doesn't work. When i call subscribe, it still shows the original JSON structure

Comment: Use `map`. `do` is for side effects and returns what it receives. Always.